# How to serve static files for local development in Django 1.4

Tags: css, django, static

I just downloaded the latest Django version (1.4.1), and I can't figure out how to serve css files when developing locally using runserver.  I've read the relevant [Django docs on static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/) and many, many questions & answers here... sounds like it's supposed to be more or less automatic, but it's not working for me.

I'm working on the polls app from the tutorial.

**404 from the log**

```
[27/Apr/2012 01:04:09] "GET /polls/ HTTP/1.1" 200 210
[27/Apr/2012 01:04:09] "GET /polls/css/styles.css HTTP/1.1" 404 2596
```

**Directory structure**

```
mysite
|-- manage.py
|-- mysite
    |-- __init__.py
    |-- settings.py
    |-- urls.py
    |-- wsgi.py
|-- polls
    |-- __init__.py
    |-- models.py
    |-- tests.py
    |-- views.py
    |-- static
        |-- css
            |-- styles.css
|-- templates
    |-- polls
        |-- index.html
```

**index.html**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/styles.css">
```

**settings.py**

```
MEDIA_ROOT = ''
MEDIA_URL = ''
STATIC_ROOT = ''
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = ()
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
"django.core.context_processors.auth",
"django.core.context_processors.debug",
"django.core.context_processors.i18n",
"django.core.context_processors.media",
'django.core.context_processors.static',
)
```

^^^ I didn't have the TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS variable in settings.py when I started the project and had to add it manually - should I be worried about that?

STATICFILES_DIRS is empty, because the css file is in a directory named static within the polls app, which is where Django looks for it automatically - right?

I also have django.contrib.staticfiles in my INSTALLED_APPS.

**urls.py**

I saw in the docs that this solution works for local development servers *other* than runserver - sounds like it shouldn't be necessary otherwise, right?  (I currently have it commented out.)

EDIT: I uncommented these lines, but did not see a change - still getting the same 404 on the css file

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

Do I have my directory structure set up wrong?  Am I missing necessary settings in settings.py?  Any help would be very much appreciated!  Thanks!

---

EDIT:

I took Mark's suggestion and read up on RequestContext.  Changing my view from:

```
return render_to_response('polls/index.html', {'latest_poll_list': latest_poll_list})
```

to

```
from django.template import RequestContext
...
return render_to_response('polls/index.html', {'latest_poll_list': latest_poll_list}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

got the /static/ url to register:

```
[27/Apr/2012 13:56:55] "GET /static/css/styles.css HTTP/1.1" 200 19
```

This fixes the problem.

Comment: did you restart your server after uncommenting the lines?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In order to use `STATIC_URL` in the template you need to be sure you are using a `RequestContext` along with adding `'django.core.context_processors.static'` to `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`. This is done for you if you are using the `render` shortcut. If you are not using a `RequestContext` then you can use the `{% get_static_prefix %}` template tag from the `staticfiles` template tag library. This is detailed in the docs here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#other-helpers

Comment: Thanks Mark! After editing my views.py to use RequestContext, I see the url for the css file as static/css/styles.css. I'm still getting a 404, but it's a step in the right direction. :)

Comment: Is `django.contrib.staticfiles` in your `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: Ah, my fault - I had moved the css file in the course of trying different options, and forgot to put it back in the right location.  It's working now.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

.'
I had the same problem, and evnetually with the same coinfuration as mentioned above this did the trick:
i added in setting.py the path to my static directory in STATICFILES_DIRS:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR,'static'),
)
```

when also in settings.py  PROJECT_DIR is set to:

```
PROJECT_DIR=os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

Answer (score 0):

From your 404, looks like you're not including {{ STATIC_URL }} in your template. That's probably the problem. instead of just "css/file", do "{{ STATIC_URL}}css/file"

Without looking too hard, your settings looks fine. If the above doesn't work, try running ./manage.py collectstatic and see if that helps (it moves static files from app directories into a project static directory).

And definitely uncomment those lines in your urls.py!
If you don't have static url patterns, when it goes to request something from /static/, it won't know what to do.

Comment: @jp42, in case you saw the answer before I edited it, I edited it :)

Comment: Hey Colleen, thanks for the reply!  I tried running collectstatic, but saw no effect... still seeing the same 404: 

[27/Apr/2012 12:53:40] "GET /polls/css/styles.css HTTP/1.1" 404 2468

I'll read up on collectstatic, though.

I'm using the {{ STATIC_URL }} tag in the head of my index.html file, like so (see above):
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/styles.css">

Comment: Did you make the changes to your template?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, forgot that enter posts. :/

Comment: Oh, I keep discovering things in your post. Definitely uncomment those lines in your urls file! Those are necessary!

Comment: Just so you know, collectstatic is meant for consolidating all your apps static files into the STATIC_ROOT for use with production serving. If everything is set up right, the dev server should locate the media in the apps static locations.

Comment: I know (I actually wrote that in my answer!) but if, for some reason, there is a problem getting to the app's static directories, but not a top level directory (I don't know exactly how that would happen, maybe a urls bug, but I'm just trying to rule things out), then it would fix that.

Comment: also, @jp42, I don't know if you originally had that line from your index.html file in your question, but if so, sorry for missing it.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me under development server: 
 1. I added "static" folder under my application "myblog" directory. 
 2. Added "myblog.css" file inside "static" folder.
 3. Linked the style sheet to my application's template, code is below.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}myblog.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

I did not change settings.py or urls.py files in order to fix css, the changes were made are only according to tutorial, so you should have the same.